# Replace a value in the dataframe if it falls in between specific values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which can be constructed as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 4, 6, 3, 2, 3, 6, 8], 
                   'B': [4, 7, 1, 5, 6, 8, 3, 9], 
                   'C': [1, 5, 3, 1, 6, 8, 9, 0], 
                   'D': [6, 3, 7, 8, 9, 4, 2, 1]})
```

The `df` looks like:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1   4   1   6
1   4   7   5   3
2   6   1   3   7
3   3   5   1   8
4   2   6   6   9
5   3   8   8   4
6   6   3   9   2
7   8   9   0   1
```

And there are 2 other variables which are to be used in substitution of values in the df:

```
mx = pd.core.series.Series([7, 8, 8, 7], index=["A", "B", "C", "D"])
dm = pd.core.series.Series([5, 8, 6, 4], index=["A", "B", "C", "D"])
```

**PROBLEM:** I want to replace all the values from the dataframe greater than the corresponding value in `dm` but less than that in `mx` with the values from `dm`. In other words, let's say for "D", I want to replace all the values between 4 and 7 with 4.

So the expected output would look something like:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1   4   1   4
1   4   7   5   3
2   5   1   3   4
3   3   5   1   8
4   2   6   6   9
5   3   8   6   4
6   5   3   9   2
7   8   9   0   1
```

I have tried using `df.apply` and `df.update` but I'm unable to make the condition. It always throws a `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Is there an efficient way to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with compare DataFrame by `Series` by [`DataFrame.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html) and
[`DataFrame.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html), chained mask by `&` for bitwise `AND` and replace by `Series` with parameter `axis=1`:

```
df = df.mask(df.ge(dm) & df.le(mx), dm, axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  1  4  1  4
1  4  7  5  3
2  5  1  3  4
3  3  5  1  8
4  2  6  6  9
5  3  8  6  4
6  5  3  9  2
7  8  9  0  1
```

Comment: This is definitely nicer than my way, just notice that according to the expected output you should use `ge` and `le` instead of `gt` and `lt`

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you if its the best way, and its probably isn't, but this works

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 4, 6, 3, 2, 3, 6, 8],
   ...:                    'B': [4, 7, 1, 5, 6, 8, 3, 9],
   ...:                    'C': [1, 5, 3, 1, 6, 8, 9, 0],
   ...:                    'D': [6, 3, 7, 8, 9, 4, 2, 1]})

In [3]: mx = pd.core.series.Series([7, 8, 8, 7], index=["A", "B", "C", "D"])
   ...: dm = pd.core.series.Series([5, 8, 6, 4], index=["A", "B", "C", "D"])

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   A  B  C  D
0  1  4  1  6
1  4  7  5  3
2  6  1  3  7
3  3  5  1  8
4  2  6  6  9
5  3  8  8  4
6  6  3  9  2
7  8  9  0  1

In [5]: for col in df.columns:
   ...:     df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x if not dm[col]<=x<=mx[col] else dm[col])
   ...:

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   A  B  C  D
0  1  4  1  4
1  4  7  5  3
2  5  1  3  4
3  3  5  1  8
4  2  6  6  9
5  3  8  6  4
6  5  3  9  2
7  8  9  0  1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-not-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code/54432584#54432584